# Как заставить мячик двигаться?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, анимация

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с кодом, не могу сообразить как заставить мяч двигаться, есть код, но что то в нём неправильно, подскажите что.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 20;

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(240, 160, ballRadius, 20, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Нужно в Draw что то добавить, добавляю но безрезультатно.

Comment: Очевидно, нужно менять координаты мячика, а уж как их менять — вам виднее

Answer (score 5):

Ваш код перерисовывает мяч на одном и том же месте снова и снова. Ведь его координаты (240, 160) не меняются. Причём, перерисовывается поверх самого себя, не стирая «экран» после предыдущего кадра. Вот пример, где эти косяки исправлены:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 20;
var ball = {x:240, y: 160}  // координаты центра мяча
  ,speed = {x: -10, y: 28}   // скорость мяча
  ,box = {x: 480, y: 200}   // ширина/высота коробки
;

function update(p) { // обновляет координаты
  ball[p] += speed[p]/10; // с учётом скорости
  if( ball[p] > box[p]) { // вылетели за дальний конец коробки?
    ball[p] = 2 * box[p] - ball[p];
    speed[p] *= -1;
  } else if( ball[p] < 0) { // вылетели за другой конец?
    ball[p] = -ball[p];
    speed[p] *= -1;
  }
}  

function draw() {
  update('x');
  update('y');

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, box.x, box.y); // очистили экран
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ballRadius, 20, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
*{padding:0;margin:0;}canvas{background:#eee}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="200"></canvas>
```

Для игровой физики рекомендую использовать готовые библиотеки. Например, посмотрите демо [matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) и сделайте что-нибудь простое, по [инструкции](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Getting-started).